# Java PrintWriter Writing Set data to .txt

Tags: java, iterator, set, printwriter

Question:  How do you increment through a set and write to .TXT using Java PrintWriter

Summary: Scans designate text file and processes the text. Then exports the results to a reporting .txt.

All aspects of this seem to work as they should up to the point I try to use the PrintWriter.
Then things go bonkers. If every thing stays as it is in the code and I print to terminal it works.If I use the PrintWriter it will create the file and then only print the second iteration of tType "text2". I have tried a number of different examples from post here but they all seem to either not fully print,print nothing at all or error.

Text file input example:

```
123456  text1   175.00  001
234567  text2   195.00  001
345678  text1   175.00  007
456789  text3   160.00  005
987654  text4   90.00   006
876543  text3   160.00  007
765432  text2   195.00  011
```

Needed Output example:

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
```

Currently getting for out put to .txt With PrintWriter

```
text2
```

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class test {

  public static void main(String[] arg){  

     Set<String> tSet= new TreeSet<>();    
    Map<String, Double> idList = new TreeMap<String, Double >();

        //Get input File.
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the full path to your file: ");

        //Error handling in try catch for file not found
        try {
            String inputFileName = console.next();

            //Scanner creation and varaibles
            File inputFile= new File(inputFileName);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);




            //Input contents  number , type, price ,ID
            //Loop


            while (input.hasNext()) 
            {
                String Num = input.next(); 
                String tType = input.next();
                tType=tType.toUpperCase();
                tSet.add(tType);
                Double tPrice=Double.parseDouble(input.next());
                String tAgent = input.next();
        //add if record does not exist, else append to existing record
                if (idList.containsKey(tAgent)) {
                    idList.put(tAgent, idList.get(tAgent) + tPrice);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    idList.put(tAgent, tPrice);
                }

            }

            input.close();

        //catch for incorrect file name or no file found
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            System.exit(1);
        }



  //Create Set iterator
  Iterator iterator;
  iterator = tSet.iterator();

  while(iterator.hasNext()){

      try {
      PrintWriter report= new PrintWriter("txtx.txt");
      report.println(iterator.next()+ " ");
     // System.out.println(iterator.next()+ " ");
      report.flush();
// report.close();
      }



    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error could not write to location");
    }   


  }


}
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new `PrintWriter` in each iteration?  Try moving that outside your while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every iteration of the output loop recreates (overwrites) the file. From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.lang.String%29)

> `fileName` - The name of the file to use as the destination of this writer. **If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size**; otherwise, a new file will be created.

Instead of creating the `PrintWriter` in the loop, create it before the loop.

```
//Create Set iterator
Iterator iterator;
iterator = tSet.iterator();

try
{
    PrintWriter report= new PrintWriter("txtx.txt");

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        report.println(iterator.next()+ " ");
        report.flush();
    }

    report.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error could not write to location");
}
```